# Probably a Stupid Issue with Git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, I'm just not sure what...  I have multiple computers that I'm working with the same BitBucket Repo on.  I can commit, push, and pull with no problems.  But, if I've pushed something from one computer, and I run a git status on another computer it shows that my branch is up to date with origin/master.

Am I just missing something here?  Or, is that normal and it will only show a status when I have updated the files on the current computer?  Thanks for clarifying this. :)

Comment: Run `git fetch` before running `git status` to see if that helps.

Comment: Did you merge changes to master? What branches are you comparing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git will not download the latest from the Git server without an explicit action from you.

So, before you run `git status` on that other computer make sure you run:

```
git fetch
```

To actually update your local branch use `git-pull` but the exact command depends on how you have your tracking branches configured.

The explicit form of `git-pull` that I like to use is:

```
git checkout branchYouWantToUpdate
git pull origin branchYouWantToUpdate
```

Comment: That looks to make sense.  I'll try it tonight when I get home and see if that  does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**git status** only show the status on your current branch.

To verify the status of your current branch on remote you have to send a **git fetch**

Someone use to schedule a cron job tp periodically send a fetch command.